# How to change the cilium DeamonSet initial container kube api address

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I am using cilium 1.14.3 as the kuberenetes v1.28.3 cni component, this is how I install the cilium:

```
helm install cilium cilium/cilium --version 1.14.3 \
   --namespace kube-system \
   --set global.nodeinit.enabled=true \
   --set global.kubeProxyReplacement=partial \
   --set global.hostServices.enabled=false \
   --set global.externalIPs.enabled=true \
   --set global.nodePort.enabled=true \
   --set global.hostPort.enabled=true \
   --set global.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
   --set config.ipam=kubernetes \
   --set global.hubble.enabled=true \
   --set global.hubble.relay.enabled=true \
   --set global.hubble.ui.enabled=true \
   --set global.hubble.metrics.enabled="{dns,drop,tcp,flow,port-distribution,icmp,http}"
```

now I want to change the kubernetes api server address, I have edited the configmap cilium-config and add this:

```
  k8s-service-host: '172.29.217.209'
  k8s-service-port: '6443'
  k8s-api-server: 'https://172.29.217.209:6443'
```

this config works for the cilium-operator, but I found the cilium DeamonSet still did not use the new api server address. Then I added the config in cilium DeamonSet like this:

```
initContainers:
        - name: config
          image: >-
            quay.io/cilium/cilium:v1.14.3@sha256:e5ca22526e01469f8d10c14e2339a82a13ad70d9a359b879024715540eef4ace
          command:
            - cilium
            - build-config
          env:
            - name: K8S_API_SERVER
              value: 'https://172.29.217.209:6443'
            - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            - name: CILIUM_K8S_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: FallbackToLogsOnError
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

seems the initial container did not read the api server address. Am I missing something? what should I do to change the kube api server address for the cilium DeamonSet initial container? I found the configuration from https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.12/gettingstarted/kubeproxy-free/#kubeproxy-free and I think it will work for 1.14.3.

this is the error log from the initial container show why I need to change the api server address:

```
level=info msg=Invoked duration="810.146µs" function="cmd.glob..func36 (build-config.go:32)" subsys=hive
level=info msg=Starting subsys=hive
level=info msg="Establishing connection to apiserver" host="https://10.96.0.1:443" subsys=k8s-client
level=info msg="Establishing connection to apiserver" host="https://10.96.0.1:443" subsys=k8s-client
level=error msg="Unable to contact k8s api-server" error="Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout" ipAddr="https://10.96.0.1:443" subsys=k8s-client
level=error msg="Start hook failed" error="Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout" function="client.(*compositeClientset).onStart" subsys=hive
level=info msg=Stopping subsys=hive
Error: failed to start: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
Usage:
  cilium build-config --node-name $K8S_NODE_NAME [flags]

Flags:
      --allow-config-keys strings        List of configuration keys that are allowed to be overridden (e.g. set from not the first source. Takes precedence over deny-config-keys
      --deny-config-keys strings         List of configuration keys that are not allowed to be overridden (e.g. set from not the first source. If allow-config-keys is set, this field is ignored
      --dest string                      Destination directory to write the fully-resolved configuration. (default "/tmp/cilium/config-map")
      --enable-k8s                       Enable the k8s clientset (default true)
      --enable-k8s-api-discovery         Enable discovery of Kubernetes API groups and resources with the discovery API
  -h, --help                             help for build-config
      --k8s-api-server string            Kubernetes API server URL
      --k8s-client-burst int             Burst value allowed for the K8s client
      --k8s-client-qps float32           Queries per second limit for the K8s client
      --k8s-heartbeat-timeout duration   Configures the timeout for api-server heartbeat, set to 0 to disable (default 30s)
      --k8s-kubeconfig-path string       Absolute path of the kubernetes kubeconfig file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dolphin.
Since you are using Helm, it is advisable to execute the command according to the documentation (please note that I am referring to version 1.14.4). Run the following Helm upgrade command for Cilium:

```
helm upgrade cilium cilium/cilium --version 1.14.4 \
--namespace kube-system \
--set k8sServiceHost=YOUR_API_IP \
--set k8sServicePort=6443
```

You can find all the relevant keys in the documentation [here](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/helm-reference/), and there is no longer a k8s-api-server key.

After executing this, you can use the following command to inspect the Cilium DaemonSet:

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe ds cilium
```

Upon doing so, you should observe the following in the output:

```
Init Containers:
 config:
  Image:     quay.io/cilium/cilium:v1.14.4@sha256:4981767b787c69126e190e33aee93d5a076639083c21f0e7c29596a519c64a2e
  Port:       <none>
  Host Port:  <none>
  Command:
   cilium
   build-config
  Environment:
    K8S_NODE_NAME:             (v1:spec.nodeName)
    CILIUM_K8S_NAMESPACE:      (v1:metadata.namespace)
    KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:   YOUR_API_IP
    KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT:   6443
```

Please note that you should replace YOUR_API_IP with the actual IP address in your specific setup.